# Average K/D of online FPS game

Tags: statistics, ratio

In online FPS games, you can get kills, and you can be killed. You are commonly scored by the ratio of your kills to deaths, simply known as "K/D". It is commonly accepted that the average K/D is $1.000$, ignoring suicides.

I'm not sure that is exactly true however given some observations.

For example...

Given two players $A$ and $B$. If $A$ has $600$ kills and $400$ deaths with a $\frac{K}{D}$ of $1.500$. $B$ therefore has $400$ kills and $600$ deaths with a $\frac{K}{D}$ of $0.667$.

The average of $1.500$ and $0.667$ is $1.083$, not $1.000$. Not only that, but it $1.500$ is $0.500$ more than $1.000$, and $0.667$ is only $0.333$ less than $1.000$. Dying appears to affect the K/D less.

My questions are...

> 1. Given a large amount of equally skilled players, is the K/D really expected to be 1.000?
> 2. Will this change if there are more skilled players than less skilled players and vice versa?

You can assume every kill results in a death, and every death is the result of a kill. "Skilled" refers to a player being more likely to get a K/D of above 1.000. I'm not looking for some specific value, rather just if the global K/D average is expected to be equal to, less than, or greater than $1.000$.

Comment: That is not a mathematical question unless you defined *skilled*. How die-hardness and killer instincts contribute to that? What are the involved probability distributions? We cannot re-construct them from their expected values only.

Comment: Skilled in this context is just being more likely to get a K/D of above 1.000. I'm not looking for a specific value to arrive that, but rather whether the global expected K/D should be equal to, greater than, or less than 1.000.

Comment: If you take as a mathematical model a "*death flux*" over a complete graph it is very likely that the average K/D ratio is pretty close to one, by trivial symmetry arguments.

Comment: In the theory of Markov chains deviations from the expected value depend on the structure of the spectrum of an adjacency matrix. Please try to turn it into a solid mathematical question, it might be interesting.

Comment: @Ahmed, based on that, would be fair then to say that the global K/D average should generally be slightly above $1.000$, but never below?

Comment: @Jack, Unfortunately I'm not familiar with more advanced math and certainly not Markov chains. I don't how to structure this is to a "solid" mathematical question but perhaps someone else is interested and knowledgeable enough.

Comment: @Ahmed, is it necessarily possible to achieve those ratios though? Would the K/Ds of every player multiplied together not have to equal $1.000$?

Comment: That gives an interesting concept to work on: a *dual* (suicidal) FPS game, in which everyone tries to get killed by you and you have to avoid as many kills as possible. Maybe through time you develop spikes, get bigger etc, making the game more and more difficult.

Comment: @Jack, I haven't seen a use of an equation like that, but it makes perfect sense. I'm sure I'll make use of such an equation in the future. Your game suggestion is very interesting indeed! :P. Anyway, for now, someone may want to move this in to chat (I lack the rep), or to provide an answer to the question.

Comment: But the product need not be $1$: note $\frac{1}{4} \frac{2}{1} \frac{3}{1}=1.5$. We have $6$ kills in numerator and $6$ deaths in the denominator.

Comment: About the second question, consider having two equally skilled players and one afk player. A and B could have 100 kills and 50 deaths each, while player C has 0 kills and 100 deaths. Average K/D would be $\frac{2 + 2 + 0}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It doesn't have to be at least $1$, consider $\frac{0}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{1}<5$. The numerators add to $6$ and denominators at to $6$. There are thus as much kills as death and the average is $\frac{4.5}{5}<1$.